# Typescript: Are computed object keys actively allowed?

Tags: typescript, types

The following compiles fine in Typescript 2.5.3:

```
interface Test {
  test: string
}

const anything = 'someDifferentKey';

const a: Test = {
  [anything]: true, // no error
  test: 'whatever'
}
```

But this doesn't:

```
interface Test {
  test: string
}

const a: Test = {
  someDifferentKey: true, // error
  test: 'whatever'
}
```

My question is - is it 'safe' to rely on computed object keys *always* being allowed to tag along with a typed object definition, or are computed properties **based on constant vales** (e.g. `"some"+"differentKey"` or the `anything` const referenced above) simply ignored for now because of a limitation of the current Typescript compiler?

**Edit for clarification:**

Read the above as: *"Does the TS spec give me any guarantee that dynamic properties won't ever cause a compilation error?"* per Juan Mendes' comment.

Answer (score 3):

[The spec](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-6.html#stricter-object-literal-assignment-checks) does not give you any guarantee that it won't ever check dynamic properties.

As the link above explains, TypeScript only checks the static part of literal objects when checking types, not dynamic [properties]. They are allowed to be on the object but you cannot retrieve it without casting or bracket access.

Your code is almost the same as if you had done

```
interface Test {
  test: string
}

const anything = 'someDifferentKey';

const a: Test = {
  test: 'whatever'
}

a[anything]: true, // no error because brackets bypass type safety
```

That is, just because you added a property to the object, it doesn't mean you can retrieve it with type safety.

```
a.someDifferentKey = false; // ERROR
// You would need
a[anything] = false;
```

Comment: I understand Juan, and that makes total sense. But what I'm referring to specifically is whether _known_ computed values (i.e. those assigned to constants) will always remain safe. In my example code, `anything` is a constant, so it wouldn't seem like too far of a stretch for a static type checker to one day realise that `[anything]` is just shorthand for `someDifferentKey`. I guess my Q was more of a speculative outlook on whether this will always be safe, or if a future TS compiler may one day start analysing constant values 'statically'.

Comment: I don't think we can guarantee that in the case of dynamic properties set  from constants, the compiler won't catch it as an error. But when would you ever use that? If it's a true dynamic property, then yeah, the compiler won't ever catch that

Comment: I ran into a use-case today where I needed to attach a dynamic key based on user input, which compiled as expected. But I realised I'd never experimented with constants, and was surprised to see too that something like `["some"+"key"]` - which could be interpreted as static literals - _also_ compiled, so it got me curious how far TS could be willing to go to analyse this kinda thing in future... or whether computed props would always be off-limits. Granted, this is more a thought experiment than an issue I expect to run into.

Comment: Still, in actual code, it doesn't make sense to do `["a" + "b"]`? Computed props are adding properties that aren't type safe, you will always have to access it with brackets? I'm not sure what your real case is. The case of const for property names (whether it's concatting other consts) is not a real case

Comment: I added _"Granted, this is more a thought experiment than an issue I expect to run into"_ above. It's just a curiosity to help me better understand the TS spec.

Comment: StackOverflow is not the best place for theoretical questions ;) See https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/

Comment: Thought experiment !== theoretical question. I was querying a concrete implementation detail of Typescript. The two valid answers are "No, it doesn't do that, and never will because that's not the spec" or "No, it doesn't do that, but someday _might_, because the spec doesn't specifically rule it out". Either way, I'd assume there's a definitive answer to warrant asking the question. The link you posted decries opinions/rants/open-ended Qs, which I fully endorse. My Q isn't intended for any of those categories.

Comment: I don't think you can get a definitive answer, I think it's theoretical, how will the TS compiler change in the future? Or maybe reword the question as "Does the TS spec give me any guarantee that dynamic properties won't ever cause a compilation error?" To which I would say there's no guarantee because it doesn't talk about it in excruciating details. See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-6.html#stricter-object-literal-assignment-checks

Comment: Edited for clarify per your suggestion.